# Hosting Admin Media Locally During Development

Tags: django

Consider the following setup:

**urls.py**

```
if not settings.PRODUCTION:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        (r'^admin-media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',{'document_root': settings.LOCAL_ADMIN_MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}),
        (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',{'document_root': settings.LOCAL_MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}),
    )
```

**settings.py**

```
if not PRODUCTION:
    ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/admin-media/'
```

So when running on the local development server the media files should be served through the runserver, right?  The media route is found, however "Permission denied" is returned for every request (but only one admin media, the regular media works fine).

So I did some checking into it.  It turns out, if the `ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX` is set to the same value as the route...

```
(r'^admin-media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', ... ),
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/admin-media/'
```

...then the runserver will *always* return "Permission denied."

However, if `ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX` is different than the route name...

```
(r'^admin-media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', ... ),
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/non-sense-prefix/'
```

... then the files will be served (though I have to manually browse to be able to see them as all the media links are broken with http://localhost:8000/non-sense-prefix/whatever.jpg).

**What's the deal here?**

In the mean time I've solved the problem by a little hack to change directories...

```
(r'^admin-media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', ... ),
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/admin-media/../admin-media/'
```

...but I would really rather configure this properly.  It seems django is trying to be smart and do something on my behalf, but messing things up in the process.  Any ideas?

**EDIT** --
I'm manually serving the admin media because I'm using grappelli which provides replacement for the admin templates/media.

Comment: I've just run into this exact issue with Grappelli (and your ugly, ingenious workaround is working for me!) - did you ever find a more elegant solution?

Comment: @Dominic -- Nope, I still have that stupid change directory path.  Since only developers see it I've just let it go.  Perhaps this has soemthing to do with how Grappelli is handling the paths.

Comment: @T. Stone - ok, thanks. +1 for your ingenious workaround, who knows how long that would've taken me to figure out.

Comment: "if production" is a great way to ensure trouble when your code reaches production untested; better to use a switch eg: "if admin".

Answer (score 1):

If you're running Grappelli, you can set the admin media when using `runserver` by specifying the command line argument `--adminmedia`. Here is an example:

```
python manage.py runserver --adminmedia=/path/to/grappelli/media
```

Where `/path/to/grappelli/media` is the complete path to your Grappelli installation's `media` directory.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specifically serve the admin media while using the development server - this should happen automatically.

Comment: I'm using grappelli which has replacement templates/media files instead of the default django admin ones.

Answer (score 0):

- I think it is simpler to just symlink in your local system to the django admin media, the same directory that you use in production, than to subject to a lot of if PRODUCTION within settings.
- As Daniel rightly pointed out, django serves admin media by default. Anymore configuration is not required. So the problem is perhaps something different. Try `chmod 777` on the templates directory, It may fix the problems.

Comment: I had considered the symlink route (as NT+ supports them), however everyone else who checks out the repo would have to do the same.  I had checked the permissions as well, and they're correct.